# Case insensitive Regex in Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, zend-framework2

How to make Regex in Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex case insensitive?

If I have

```
$route = Regex::factory(array(
    'regex' => '/blog/(?<id>Test)',
    'defaults' => array(
        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\BlogController',
        'action'     => 'view',
        'format'     => 'html',
    ),
    'spec' => '/blog/%id%',
));
```

`'regex' => '/blog/(?<id>Test)i',` doesnt work.
`'regex' => '/blog/(?<id>Testi)',` also doesnt work.

How to solve this?

Comment: You can't specify regex modifiers for regex route: `preg_match('(\G' . $this->regex . ')', $path, $matches, null, $pathOffset);`

Comment: How to use this preg_match() ? Don't get it :( . I have this route in my  module.config.php

Comment: It is quote from the RegexRoute code to show that it does not accept modifiers. You can make custom Route to make regex case insensitive or you can open Pull Request to add that functionality to RegexRoute in next release.

Answer (score 0):

your [regex modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) syntax is incorrect, try this:

`/blog/(?i)(?<id>Test)`